# Opening many shape at the same time

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile

It may seem like a simple question but I haven't found a solution.
I have a structure of directories with many shapefiles inside. Is there a method to open all these shapefiles at the same time with ArcMap?

The function "add data" forces me to do it for every directory separately.

Comment: use ArcCatalog use the search for shapefiles on the highest directory then select all (CTRL+A) drag and drop into arcmap.

Answer (score 1):

You could first create a [Layer Package](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000013000000) that contains all of your data and symbology for all the layers.  From that point on, you can just load the Layer Package the way you would a layer, and everything just gets loaded up.

> Other users will be able to add layer packages directly into their
>   maps without having to know how to access the database or classify the
>   data.

Or, of course, you could just load the data and save it in an MXD, and re-open the MXD...